# Batch File Programming with Findstr and Regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

First off, I am not a batch file and/or regex programmer.  ;)

Using batch file programming to parse filenames beginning with "T" that may be immediately followed by "2" AND "2" may be immediately followed by any of the integers 0-9.  All the files in the folder will be named the same beginning with "T" and followed by integers 1-29.  For example:
T1_... or T12_... or T2_... or T22_....

In this particular case ...

a) Filenames with T2 should fail the regex.  Errorlevel should be 1.

b) Filenames with T12 should fail the regex.  Errorlevel should be 1.

c) Filenames with T20 - T29 should pass the regex.  Errorlevel should be 0.

Problem: These results are not seen.  Errorlevel appears to be 0, always.

```
echo on

dir *.bin /b | findstr /r /c:"^[T][2][?=0123456789]*"
if errorlevel 0 goto :regular

:special
   echo special
   pause
   exit /B 0

:regular
   echo regular
   pause
   exit /B 0
```

Two web based regex evaluators say my regex is valid as written when tested against all combinations, pass and fail.

What is going on with the "findstr" regex that it does not produce the outlined behavior (a-c)?  Or, am I not using errorlevel correctly?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: A leading or trailing `x*` on a regex (where `x` is any regular expression) might as wel be left off as far as matching is concerned. `foox*` and `foo` both match `foo` and don't fail matching if `foo` is followed by something other than `x`. (If you capture the matching string for further processing, there may be situations where you want to include as much as possible in the match; but here, you're not doing anything like that.)

Comment: You might not realize that `[?=0123]` matches any one character which is `?` or `=` or `0` or `1` or `2` or `3`.  There is no need to put T or 2 in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your regex is not right. `findstr` has limited regex capabilities, but even in a full-fledged regex engine it would not be quite correct. Here's a better one:

```
^T2[0-9]_
```

Starts with `T`, followed by `2`, followed by a single character from the `0-9` range, followed by an underscore `_` (I figure), followed by anything (implicit).

---

Next, the `/c` parameter in `findstr` means *"Uses specified string as a literal search string."* and that's contradicting what we actually want.

With that we end up with:

```
findstr /r "^T2[0-9]_"
```

---

Next, filtering the list of files in a directory:

```
dir /b *.bin 2>NUL | findstr /r "^T2[0-9]_"
```

Here the `2>NUL` redirects STDERR of `dir` to `NUL`, so "file not found" or the like is not printed.

By the way, the following would never generate errors in the `dir` command, simply by moving the file extension check to the regex:

```
dir /b | findstr /r "^T2[0-9]_.*\.bin$"
```

---

Next, doing something depending on whether we matched or not matched:

```
dir /b *.bin 2>NUL | findstr /r "^T2[0-9]_" >NUL && (
    @echo Match!
) || (
    @echo No Match!
)
```

This uses the properties of `&&` and `||`, namely to check out the errorlevel and run the following command when it is 0 (`&&`) or otherwise (`||`). I tend to like that construct better than `goto`.

Also this uses `>NUL` to suppress the regular output of `findstr`.

---

Next, doing something for each matching filename (that's better than using `goto` as well):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %f in (`dir /b *.bin 2^>NUL ^| findstr /r "^T2[0-9]_"`) do (
    @echo Match: %f
)
```

Here, `usebackq` enables the use of backticks to enclose a command, `delims=` switches off the default "split at whitespace" behavior of `for`. This way filenames with a space won't get broken up into tokens. Also note that in a quoted command we must escape special characters like the pipe `|` and the `>` with a `^`.

---

Next, the above but for use in a batch file:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b *.bin 2^>NUL ^| findstr /r "^T2[0-9]_"`) do (
    echo Match: %%f
)
```

Here we must escape `%` as `%%` (special rule that applies to `for` loop index variables).

Comment: Thank you all for helping with this.  I appreciate the very fast response.  I tried Tomalak's match/nomatch code and it worked "out of the box".  I do want to study this further and try all the variations from you both.  If you have some good book references to learn batch file programming and REGEX programming I'd be very grateful for that.  --Ernie  :)

Comment: Windows batch file programming. Avoid if you can, it's a long and painful path. ;) If you are new to programming, I recommend starting with a real programming language - Python, or since you are on Windows, Powershell (though this is also rather tough). Powershell comes pre-installed with every Windows, Python does not. Python is easier to learn and much more straightforward. For regex I can only recommend [the book](http://regex.info/book.html) by Jeffrey Friedl.

Answer (score 0):

`findstr` uses a regex subset to find a string in a file.

Hence, your command is *probably* yielding `errorlevel` of 0 because the question being asked is "is there a string matching this *anwhere* in the 'file' generated by `dir`?"

What you appear to be attempting to do is to show those files that *do* and those that *do not* match your pattern.

So - if you just want a *list* of the files, then

```
dir /b /A-D |findstr /R "regex"
```

should accomplish that task, noting:

`/a-d` means "don't show directorynames"
`/r` is the default hence is redundant
`/r /v` could replace `/r` meaning "do *not* match the *regex*"
switches are case-insensitive.

Another approach would be

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
 echo %%a|findstr /r "regex" >nul
 if errorlevel 1 (call :nonmatch "%%a"
 ) else (
  call :match "%%a"
 )
)
```

where `[non]match` are subroutines:

```
....
goto :eof

:match
echo %~1 matches
goto :eof
```

`%%a` is assigned each name from the `dir` command in turn, and is then examined by `findstr`, outputting to `nul` and setting `errorlevel` to 0 if the `regex` is passed, `1` if not. The `errorlevel` is then examined and one of the two subroutines is executed, with the first parameter `%1` being the (quoted) filename.

Note:
The *metavariable* `%%a` is case-sensitive
`findstr` could also have the `/i` switch to make the *regex* analysis case-insensitive.
The construct `goto :eof` (case-insensitive) is *defined* in `cmd` as "go to end of file"

Now - as for `regex` itself, as I said, it's a subset. I'd use `T2[0-9]_` and add the `/b` switch to the `findstr`, yielding `findstr /r /i /b "T2[0-9]_"` meaning "begins, case-insensitive, with *regex* T2*a_digitunderscore*"

You could also omit the `/b` and use `"^T2[0-9]_"` in theory - I have a personal preference for the `/b` version.

Answer (score 0):

`findstr` supports limited regular expression, but, for your application, you could use `findstr /r "^T2[0-9]".

For full Javascript compatible regular expressions, how about using `cscript` instead?

```sh
@echo off

dir *.txt /b | cscript //nologo match.js "^T2[0-9]"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto :regular

:special
   echo special
   pause
   exit /B 0

:regular
   echo regular
   pause
   exit /B 0
```

Where `match.js` is defined as:

```js
if (WScript.Arguments.Count() !== 1) {
  WScript.Echo("Syntax: match.js regex");
  WScript.Quit(1);
}
var rx = new RegExp(WScript.Arguments(0), "i");
var matched = false;
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  var str = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
  if (str.match(rx)) {
    WScript.Echo(str);
    matched = true;
  }
}
if (!matched) {
  WScript.Quit(1);
}
```